# NodeJS: Best way to watch over files recusively?

Tags: node.js, dropbox, watch, node-webkit

I'm writing cross-platform client for file hosting service (something like dropbox). I'm using [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) for this.

So the question is: what is the best way to realize cross-platform watching of file changes and how dropbox do it? (maybe someone know?). The nodes [fs.watch](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) method cannot watch over directory recursively. I found [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) library, but I doubt that it will acceptably handle more than 100K files. Maybe someone can help me?